# Указывание емайла при задании вопроса незарегистрированным участником

Tags: поддержка

Когда незарегистрированный участник задаёт свой первый вопрос ему необходимо указать свой адрес электронной почты. На эту почту приходит письмо для завершения регистрации. Перейдя по этой ссылке можно ввести пароль и учётная запись будет подтверждена.

Однако в реальности получится две учётные записи:

1. Учётная запись незарегистрированного участника, именно эта учётная запись будет являться автором вопроса.
2. Учётная запись зарегистрированного участника, которая формально не имеет отношения к первой учётной записи.

Проблема в том, что у участника остаётся доступ только ко второй учётной записи, поэтому, например, он не сможет отредактировать свой вопрос.

Зачем тогда при задании вопроса нужно указывать адрес почты?

Comment: вроде в куки что-то пишется, поэтому отредактировать вопрос может, но лишь с того браузера с которого задавал (не считая ТОР, анонимные режимы и пр).

Comment: Обычно в таких случаях учетки весьма оперативно объедняются

Comment: Выглядит как какой-то костыль если честно) Зачем нужна вторая учётка, кажется что можно было бы при подтверждении адреса почты снимать статус "незарегистрированный" с первой учётки, без создания новой второй учётки